# Issue in rendering ionic component from api

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it Possible to render component  from a server ?

```
for e.g if I get below code from api 

<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <div text-center>
            <h3 text-uppercase>Std</h3>
            <h1>test1</h1>
            <p>test2</p>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

And in my html file

```
<ion-grid [innerHTML]="homedata.page_content">
```

when i use this method it is changing `<ion-row>` to `<div>`. It is possible to render ionic component from api??